# Relationship between order of a group acting on a set and faithfulness

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

I am trying to prove (or to disprove) that $\forall n,m \in \mathbb{N}$ where $\gcd (n, m) = 1$ and $n, m \geq 2$, $\exists G$ a group such that $|G| = n$ and $\exists X$ a set such that $|X| = m$ such that $G$ acts on $X$ such that there are no trivial orbits (no fixed points). I do not know where to start.

If this is untrue, then is there some restriction such that it becomes true?

Answer (score 0):

I $G$ acts faithfully on a set $X$ then we can define a new action on any set $X\subset Y$ setting $g(a)=a$ for any $a\in Y\setminus X$ and $Y$ can have any  cardinality

Answer (score 0):

Let $G=S_3$ and let $X=S_3/\langle (12)\rangle\cup S_3/\langle (123)\rangle$. This set has five elements and the action is faithful.

Comment: So would this be true for *every* group and set that have orders that are co-prime?

Comment: @Kiar No, just one group and one set. You use $\exists$ in your question, which implies that only one example is required.

Comment: @Kia And the question has changed since I answered it.

Comment: Sorry, I rephrased it. I'm trying to see if there is some sort of relationship between the order of the group and set and it being faithful or not

Comment: @Kia As the other answer says, the divisibility had nothing to do with it. Only the size.

Comment: I see. Because there are questions like let $G$ be a group that acts on $X$ a set and let $|G| = 22$ and $|X| = 12$. Then we use the fact that the orbits divide $G$ to conclude that there must be a fixed point in $X$. So this action is not faithful. I wanted to see if there is some generalization.

Comment: @Kia Faithful does not mean there are no fixed points. It just means that no element acts trivially. Do you mean a free action?

Comment: @Kiar And the argument you're using for a fixed point only works for a $p$-group. As soon as more than one prime divides the order, the fact that the orbits divide the size of the group implies nothing about the size of the whole set. My example is a free action and the order of the set is coprime to the order of the group.

Comment: Doesn't faithful mean that the kernel of the action is 1?

Comment: @Kia Yes, which means that there's no element that fixes *all* points. There can still be points that are fixed by all elements.

Comment: Ahhhh, so what I'm referring to is just that there exists a fixed point